# Combine multiple lines into 1 string with stream reader

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a decently sized file (95K lines) that i need to parse through.  For the following sample data...

```
<FIPS>10440<STATE>AL<WFO>BMX
8                 32.319   32.316  -86.484  -86.487   32.316  -86.484
32.316  -86.484
102               32.501   31.965  -85.919  -86.497   32.496  -86.248
32.448  -86.181   32.432  -86.189   32.433  -86.125   32.417  -86.116
32.406  -86.049   32.419  -86.023   32.337  -85.991   32.333  -85.969
32.276  -85.919   32.271  -85.986   32.250  -85.999   31.968  -85.995
31.965  -86.302   32.052  -86.307   32.051  -86.406   32.245  -86.410
32.276  -86.484   32.302  -86.491   32.332  -86.475   32.344  -86.497
32.364  -86.492   32.378  -86.463   32.405  -86.460   32.414  -86.396
32.427  -86.398   32.433  -86.350   32.412  -86.310   32.441  -86.325
32.487  -86.314   32.473  -86.288   32.488  -86.260   32.501  -86.263
32.496  -86.248
```

What I need to do is read from one FIPS to the next FIPS and combine the lines within each group into one giant line like the following...

```
<FIPS>10440<STATE>AL<WFO>BMX 8 32.319   32.316  -86.484  -86.487   32.316  -86.484 32.316  -86.484...
<FIPS>10440<STATE>AL<WFO>BMX 102 32.501   31.965  -85.919  -86.497   32.496  -86.248 32.448  -86.181...
```

I currently have the following code (about my 6th variation for the day).  What am I missing?

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(winterBoundsPath))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine().Trim();


                if (!Char.IsLetter(line[0]))
                {
                    if (line.Contains("<FIPS>"))
                    {
                        var lineReplace = line.Replace('<', ' ').Replace('>', ' ');
                        string[] rawData = lineReplace.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                        temp = new WinterJsonModel
                        {
                            FIPS = rawData[1],
                            State = rawData[3],
                            Center = rawData[5],
                            polyCoords = new List<polyCoordsJsonData>()
                        };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string[] rawData2 = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                        if (rawData2.Count() > 1)
                        {
                            allValues.Add(listPointValue);
                            listPointValue = new List<string>();
                        }

                        // Add values to line
                        foreach (string value in rawData2)
                        {
                            listPointValue.Add(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I just realized that this isnt the most current version.  My apologies.  It may be easier to show me a sample of how to do this without tyring to fix my current code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've been parsing text files for over 40 years.  Code below is sample of what I've done

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Oppgave3Lesson1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WinterJsonModel data = new WinterJsonModel();
            data.ParseFile(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class WinterJsonModel
    {
        public static List<WinterJsonModel> samplData = new List<WinterJsonModel>();

        public string fips { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string wfo { get; set; }
        public List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();


        public void ParseFile(string winterBoundsPath)
        {
            WinterJsonModel winterJsonModel = null;

            Group group = null;
            List<KeyValuePair<decimal, decimal>> values = null;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(winterBoundsPath))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine().Trim();
                    if (line.Length > 0)
                    {
                        if (line.StartsWith("<FIPS>"))
                        {
                            winterJsonModel = new WinterJsonModel();
                            WinterJsonModel.samplData.Add(winterJsonModel);
                            string[] rawData = line.Split(new char[] { '<', '>' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                            winterJsonModel.fips = rawData[1];
                            winterJsonModel.state = rawData[3];
                            winterJsonModel.wfo = rawData[5];
                            group = null; // very inportant line
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            decimal[] rawData = line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => decimal.Parse(x)).ToArray();
                            //if odd number of numbers in a line
                            if (rawData.Count() % 2 == 1)
                            {
                                group = new Group();
                                winterJsonModel.groups.Add(group);
                                group.id = (int)rawData[0];
                                //remove group number from raw data
                                rawData = rawData.Skip(1).ToArray();
                            }
                            for (int i = 0; i < rawData.Count(); i += 2)
                            {
                                group.values.Add(new KeyValuePair<decimal, decimal>(rawData[i], rawData[i + 1]));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
    public class Group
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public List<KeyValuePair<decimal, decimal>> values = new List<KeyValuePair<decimal, decimal>>();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a more heavyweight solution than mine and probably a little overkill for the problem, but regex is definitely the way to go if it's ever more complicated than a whitespace character and a carriage return. +1

Comment: The Regex is only for the header lines, not for the numbers.  I was thinking of following.  What do you think? string[] header = input.Split(new char[] {'<','>'}, StringSpitOptions.Remove EmptyEntries).ToArray();  fips = header[1];state = header[3];wfo = header[5];

Comment: I’m going to try jdweng’s version as well.  Thanks to you both.

Comment: @jdweng - so i was working with your code tonight and for the life of me I couldn't figure out why it was not working.  I was not getting an errors until I ran it.  After looking at the data more thoughtfully I realized that the data isnt the same all the way through this 95k  line file.  What I am seeing is this <FIPS>90000<STATE>FL<WFO>TBW
  10                 29.141   29.139  -83.035  -83.038   29.139  -83.035
   29.139  -83.035
   8                 29.141   29.141  -83.036  -83.036   29.141  -83.036
   29.141  -83.036

Comment: The '10' after 'TBW' and the '8' after -83.035 are, for the lack of a better term, subsets.  so what I would need is the following  <FIPS>90000<STATE>FL<WFO>TBW 10 29.141 29.139 -83.035 -83.038 29.139 -83.035 29.139 -83.035     and     <FIPS>90000<STATE>FL<WFO>TBW 8 29.141 29.141 -83.036 -83.036 29.141 -83.036 29.141 -83.036.   follow me?  Can you help me with this one?

Comment: I understand.  Can you update you sample code with subset lines.  I need to know what data is on each line.  The examples in the comments don't clearly show me where the new lines begin.  Lines without subsets looks like there a 8 numbers per line.  Lines with subsets have more than 8.  Not sure.  So it looks like the 'else' need to check the number of values on the line and handle multiple cases.

Comment: I updated code and tested.  Not sure if it going to work.  I assume the value are pairs so update code to put number in pairs.  Then assume if the line contain 1 number it is a group number.  You will never get data with one value because the values come in pairs.  Also made group number -1 when a group number doesn't exist.

Comment: I updated the sample data.  I will try out your code now.  Thanks

Comment: Looks like group number is first number of the line.  So when there are an odd number of values on a line, it is the first line of the group and group number is first value.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the sample you've given, the line breaks are CRLF characters.  This means you really only need to know two things. 
1. If the line contains "FIPS" as a `string` literal enclosed as a tag
2. if you've reached the end of a line that has a carriage return.

I'm going to ignore the JSON bit for now, because it's not part of your question. I'm assuming this means you have the JSON well-handled and if we get these `strings` how you want them, you've got it from there.

```
var x = new List<string>();
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine().Trim();
    if (line.Contains("<FIPS>"))
    { 
        x.Add(line.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " "));  
    }
    else
    { 
        var s = String.Concat(x.Last(), line.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty), " "); 
        x[x.Count - 1] = s;
    }
}
```

Much of the point here is to separate the organization of the data away from actually putting it into your object.   From here, you can iterate through the list in a `foreach`, creating new objects based on the results of `string.Split()` on each `string` in your `List<string>.`

Comment: MAN!  I hate these simple solutions.  I always make it harder than it is.  Outside of some formatting that I have to take care of, this is exactly what I am looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: You cannot put line together when group number exist.  See OPs comments in other answer.